# Swift 2.0 Random EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, afnetworking, swift2

I'm running into some really strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes which are totally reproducible with the last 2 **Xcode 7 Beta** versions (including the GM from last night):

When running my application, AFNetworking crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message in AFURLConnectionOperation.m line 154. More precisely, here is the stacktrace:

```
thread #1: tid = 0x23b173, 0x000000010b89beaf CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 767, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x000000010b89beaf CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 767
    frame #1: 0x000000010b89bb28 CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 120
  * frame #2: 0x0000000105a4507e MyApp`-[AFURLConnectionOperation .cxx_destruct](self=0x00007fc4d873aa20, _cmd=(null)) + 494 at AFURLConnectionOperation.m:154
    frame #3: 0x000000010af637bb libobjc.A.dylib`object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 127
    frame #4: 0x000000010af6e390 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance + 93
    frame #5: 0x000000010b94e7c6 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) __dealloc_zombie] + 150
    frame #6: 0x00000001087ee9df Foundation`-[NSOperation dealloc] + 89
    frame #7: 0x0000000105a3dca2 MyApp`-[AFURLConnectionOperation dealloc](self=0x00007fc4d873aa20, _cmd="dealloc") + 162 at AFURLConnectionOperation.m:216
    frame #8: 0x000000010af78afe libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 232
    frame #9: 0x0000000105a31dd1 MyApp`__destroy_helper_block_((null)=0x00007fc4d8b27000) + 65 at AFHTTPRequestOperation.m:0
    frame #10: 0x000000010d1226b1 libsystem_blocks.dylib`_Block_release + 128
    frame #11: 0x000000010d0a549b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #12: 0x000000010d08d34b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
    frame #13: 0x000000010b8a63e9 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #14: 0x000000010b867939 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2073
    frame #15: 0x000000010b866e98 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    frame #16: 0x000000010dd2cad2 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #17: 0x00000001095c9676 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
    frame #18: 0x0000000105767d3f MyApp`main(argc=7, argv=0x00007fff5a541620) + 111 at main.m:33
    frame #19: 0x000000010d0da92d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

I set enabled Zombie Objects in my scheme and got the following error

```
*** -[NSMutableURLRequest release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fc4d8acc460
```

Would any one of you have an idea what is causing the crash? Using **Xcode 6** works like a charm but I'd really like to use the new Swift features in my code ...

Comment: May be AFNetworking developer still working to make their API compatible with Swift 2.0.  Question itself a one reason that I minimise use of third party APIs.

Comment: You are [not alone](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2937) my friend.

Comment: yes seems like 7.1 messes a bit things up. i have the same issue with a code that worked fine with Xcode 7 beta 6 but now doesn't with 7.1

Comment: Do you think its safe to assume that this is a bug in AFNetworking or is it a bug within the Swift compiler (since it appears to be dealing with messed up ARC code somehow)

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question and leave this here for anyone out there who might be running into the same problem:

Apparently, the Swift 2.0 compiler doesn't like closures being passed an `inout` parameter. I had a closure in place which could be used to further customize my request which took an object of type `NSMutableURLRequest` as an inout parameter. Once changing this closure to simply return the request and removing the `inout` everything works as expected again ...

Comment: can u tell me what actually u did. i too facing same problem